# mysql minutes to hours and minutes

Tags: mysql, time, decimal

I have a table that return minutes from a task and I'd like to convert into hours and minutes.

my select is:

```
select
m.mat_nome as 'Matéria',
round(
    sum(
        case when Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60 = 0 
            then Minute(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))
            else Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60
        end
    )/60
 ,2)
as 'tempo' from estudos_realizados e
left join materias m on e.mat_id = m.mat_id;
```

so this is returning 100 minutes from my table and 1.67 when divided by 60.
I'd like to get the result 1h40m The hours and minutes.

This is possible? How can I divide the number to 60 and mod the decimals to 60?

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should look up FLOOR() function, and simple math. You need something like

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(minutes/60),'h ',MOD(minutes,60),'m')
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 7):

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(minutes/60),':',LPAD(MOD(minutes,60),2,'0'))
```

a variation on Damir Kasipovic's code: 
this converts 62 minutes to '1:02'

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply do something like this?

```
select convert(date_add('2000-01-01', interval 146 minute), time);
```

This returns `02:26:00`

Or the following if you want to specify return format

```
select date_format(date_add('2000-01-01', interval 146 minute), '%h:%i');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working! Thanks!

```
select
    m.mat_nome as 'Matéria',
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(
            sum(
                case when Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60 = 0 
                    then Minute(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))
                    else Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60
                end
            )/60
        ),'h', 
        MOD(
            sum(
                case when Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60 = 0 
                    then Minute(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))
                    else Hour(TIMEDIFF(est_horario_inicial, est_horario_final))*60
                end
            )
        ,60)
    , 'm')
    as 'tempo' from estudos_realizados e
left join materias m on e.mat_id = m.mat_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following facts: hours = floor /60 
 minutes = (-hours*60