# How to convert number of minutes to hh:mm format in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a select query that has DURATION column to calculate number of Minutes . I want to convert those minutes to hh:mm format.

Duration has values like 0, 120, 2402165

For example:

```
NULL becomes 00:00

0 becomes 00:00

60 becomes 01:00

2402165 becomes 40036:05
```

I have already tried using different queries, but with undesirable results:

```
SELECT CAST(60/60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(60%60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(MINUTE,2402165,0),114)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025363/mysql-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes

This is not what I want, which is why I raised different question.

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN DURATION/60 <= 9 THEN '0' + CAST(DURATION/60 AS NVARCHAR(max)) ELSE CAST(DURATION/60 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) END + ':' + CASE WHEN DURATION%60 <= 9 THEN '0' + CAST(DURATION%60 AS NVARCHAR(max)) ELSE CAST(DURATION%60 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))END AS Total

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @minute int
SET @minute=2402165

SELECT CASE WHEN SIGN(@minute) = -1.0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END + CONVERT(varchar(10),ABS(@minute)/60) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(10),ABS(@minute)%60)
```

Comment: pls check the result of:
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute,2402165,0),108)

it shows 04:05 which is incorrect