# How to convert seconds to hours in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

I need to convert seconds to hours in decimal format in MySQL. For example: 150 minutes is 2.5 hours, 75 minutes is 1.25 hours.

I can't see Apache SuperSet supporting HH:mm format, so I think the decimal format would be a better fit. Is there any way built-in way for this conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql minutes to hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025363/mysql-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: Err, divide by 3600?

Comment: @targhs No it doesn't. That guy wanted hours and minutes. This guy wants hours and a fraction.

Comment: 'HH:MM:SS' => TIME_TO_SEC() => SS => /3600 => HH

Answer (score 0):

To convert 150 minutes to 2.5 one can use:

```
select 150*60 / 3600.0;
```

output: `2.5000`

First you need to multiply the number of minutes to get the number of seconds (like stated in the question title), and then you can divide by 3600 (which is 60*60).

The short way is to do: `SELECT 150/60;`

Comment: To convert 150 minutes to 2.5 hours one can use `select 150/60.0`. The additional multiplication is pointless. And the OP has seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @user207421: It is unclear if OP has seconds or minutes, The title of this question is about seconds, the examples (in the question) are about minutes.  But the question is about basic mathematics, because "converting seconds to hours in MySQL" (like the title says) is done the same way as "converting seconds to hours"  Nothing special has to be done in MySQL to do the conversion.